# How to open Terms And Conditions "ACTIVITY " (NOT DIALOG BOX) in Android studio?

Tags: android

I have developed an application and I want to make my 1st page like a terms and conditions activity and then if the user accepts it never shows on that device again. If the user rejects the terms and conditions "activity" it will be showing every time the application starts.

My question is "how can I implement the code?"

I did a shared preference boolean check but the problem is that the ACTIVITY opens only once and even if the user hasnt clicked the accept button then also it does not show in the second run .

Please Help me solve this issue?

Check Out my code

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean agreed = prefs.getBoolean("agreed", false);
            if (!agreed) {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, termsandconditions.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
                showTermsandConditions();
            } else {
                Intent registerIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LanguageActivity.class);
                SplashScreen.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
            }
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}

private void showTermsandConditions() {


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
    editor.apply(


    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in class termsandcondition, on submit of activity after accepting the conditions

```
private void showTermsandConditions() {


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
    editor.apply(


    );
}
```

Comment: thanks i think this is the right solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a *AlertDialog* with a `Checkbox` and a `Button` below in your *Launcher Activity* from *AndroidMainfest.xml* or putting the therms in your `Activity` with a `Button`, your choice. To get control if the user already accepted it put the values in your *SharedPreferences* file. So the **Preferences.class** will be like:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Preferences {

    private Context mContext;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private String FILE_NAME = "app.Preferences";
    private int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    private String KEY_THERMS = "KEY_THERMS";

    public Preferences(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, MODE);
        editor = preferences.edit();
    }

    public void setTherms(String value) {
        editor.putString(KEY_THERMS, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getTherms() {
        return preferences.getString(KEY_THERMS, "NO");
    }

}
```

In your *Launcher Activity* will have something like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_therms);

    Preferences preferences = new Preferences(this);
    String therms = preferences.getTherms();
    if(therms.equals("YES")){
        Intent intentMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMain);
    }else{
        //show therms to accept

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preferences.setTherms("YES");
        }
        });
    }


}
```

This is just a **example model** that solves the problem. There is a lot ways to do it.

Comment: thanks but i am a newbie in android studio , It would be nice of you if you could give me the activity code instead of alert dialog one.... but Thanks for your help..

Comment: the second code is from Activity, in `onCreate()` method